# How do I see the full logs of a local invocation of a Lambda via SAM?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

[I am using the default HelloWorld example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html)
My code is:

```
let response;
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(event);
    try {
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world'
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response
};
```

Everything works as expected. I am starting it with `sam local start-api` or `sam local start-api --debug`

My questions, Where do I see the output of `console.log(event);`
Currently I can only see a `{`.
I if put there a string, like 'AAAAAAAA' I would see that in the terminal where I typed `sam local start-api` (as expected).

what am I missing so I can see full local logs?

Comment: did you try, `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));` or `sam local start-api --log-file logfile.txt`

Comment: I tried the ``` --log-file``` but with full path. Will try without and casting it to string and will update the question once I know

Comment: @petey put console.log(JSON.stringify(event)); as an answer and i'll accept it - should have figured it myself :-D (too much browser side developing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, put in `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to a string from logging,

`console.log(JSON.stringify(event));`

You can then see the logging in the terminal/command-prompt via

`sam local start-api`

Or have it log to a file with:

`sam local start-api --log-file logfile.txt`

Comment: Piggy-backing to add:

You can use `--log-file /dev/stdout` to just log in the same window as your sam command. This will make logs a little jumbled though.